# Thermostats with or without variable temperature differential (swing)

Tags: hvac, thermostat, furnace, air-conditioning, forced-air

I am looking at replacing my thermostat, and don't really need or want one with geosync.  I am thinking of the honeywell RTH9585wf.  Currently I have a lux that is not wifi but programmable.  It offers temperature  swing between .5 and 3 degrees.  It is currently set at 1.25.

The honeywell does not have a variable swing feature, and is set at 1 degree. Or for my setup with forced air and high efficiency gas it would cycle 3 -5 times per hour.  I contacted honeywell and asked them this and that is what the rep stated.  He mentioned that the honeywell could come on before the 1 degree difference is met, in order to maintain a 1 degree difference.  I am not sure how the Lux works with that.  He also mentioned that if you set the thermostat for water steam equipment (something like that), then it is set at 1 CPH.

I use if for both heat and cold in ohio so we get cold weather and hot weather. Am I losing to much of a feature with no temperature swing on the honeywell?  Is 3 - 5 CPH to much, or is this normal operation.  Or if anyone else has thermostat recommendations I am open to that also. Again I don't really need the nest or those types but would like to have wifi to control it when away for long periods of time.  Thanks

Comment: 1 degree _is_ the swing. It's just not variable. You've misunderstood the term.

Comment: Yup oops,  edited and fixed.  Any suggestions on if it is better to have a variable swing or not?  Again it sounds like 3 - 5 CPH would be the case with the honeywell

Comment: Unfortunately I have relatively limited experience with HVAC systems. We do have a number of knowledgeable folks around though, and I'm sure they'll come along soon.

Comment: If your current one is set to 1.25 degrees, it doesn't sound to me like fixed 1 degree will be at all noticeable.